# Detecting when signalR hub is ready after hub.start()

Tags: knockout.js, signalr, signalr.client

I have a parent and child viewModel.  The parent viewmodel starts the signalR connection:

```
$.connection.hub.start()
```

The child viewmodel - one that loads only when the user accesses chat - does the following:

```
chat.server.addUserToChat(self.currentUsername()).done(function() {
    alert('added');
});
```

The problem is, the child call is happening before the parent call.  I can fix this with a setTimeOut of 1 second, but ideally I could do something like this:

```
$.connection.hub.ready(function(){chat.server.addUserToChat(self.currentUsername()).done(function() {
        alert('added');
    });});
```

Is there anything like this in signalR?  Or do I need to use timeouts / pub/sub between viewmodels?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be more an issue of structuring your application.
You can store the deferred object returned by `hub.start()` in some global object and access it in your child viewmodel:

```
window.chatApp = {
    hubConnector: $.connection.hub.start()
};

// in your child viewmodel
chatApp.hubConnector.done(function () {
    chat.server.addUserToChat(self.currentUsername()).done(function () {
        alert('added');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
  // hub is now ready
  chat.server.addUserToChat(self.currentUsername()).done(function() {
    alert('added');
  });
});
```

Comment: I can't do this because I'm starting the hub connection from the parent viewmodel, I need to know when it's done from the child.