# SignalR Client in PartialView Not Receiving

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub

I'm still getting the basics of SignalR down.  I'd like to use it in different parts of my website, so I was thinking I could start the connection in the main layout, and add client methods in sub views.

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21080143/detecting-when-signalr-hub-is-ready-after-hub-start) I have :

```
window.hub = $.connection.hub.start();
```

in my Layout.cshtml, and

```
window.hub.done(function () {
   $.connection.notificationHub.server.joinScannerGroup(1);
   alert("in sub view");
});
```

in my subview, which works.  The hub is connected, and the method `JoinScannerGroup()` is called.  However, if i try to add:

```
$.connection.notificationHub.client.scanReceived = function (text) {
    alert("scan received");
};
```

anywhere in the javascript for the subview, it never gets called.  Maybe I'm undertanding it wrong, but I'd like to connect on the mainpage, and then allow any subpages to receive client calls.

Also, if I move the `$.connection.start()` into the subview, it does work correctly.  Am I understanding it wrong?

Comment: are this javascript code is executed on document.ready? or it just placed as it

Comment: currently I have `$connection.hub.start()` within the document ready, and the others outside.  Good point, I'll test that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to either add all client hub methods before you call `hub.start()`, or you need to add at least one hub method before calling `hub.start()` (so SignalR will subscribe to the hub) and then add all other hub methods like this:

```
$.connection.notificationHub.on('scanReceived ', function (text) {
    alert("scan received");
});
```

(also see [documentation](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#callclient))

Comment: fantastic thank you very much!  I just missed this going through the documentation.  You are the man.

Comment: As a follow-up, is it considered okay to have a dummy client hub method to call?  I have no need for one before I call `hub.start()` but clearly i need it to connect to the hub

Comment: whether that method gets called at all isn't really important, so you can use a dummy; the other side of that question is a matter of design - personally, I would try to keep the code that is responsible for connectivity separate from the client-side business logic (so I would probably not use a closure around the hub method; instead I would delegate from the hub method to an object that knows what to do when it receives a scan)

Comment: Right, I imagine in the end I'd treat the Hub like a controller and use my service layer for the logic